# WTForms validation error not working

Tags: python, flask, wtforms, flask-wtforms, flask-login

I am trying to create a login form wherein if the username is blank, it throws an error.

```
from flask import Flask, render_template
from flask_wtf import FlaskForm
from wtforms import StringField, PasswordField, BooleanField
from wtforms.validators import InputRequired, Email, length, ValidationError

app = Flask(__name__)
app.config['SECRET_KEY'] = 'This is a secret'
class LoginForm(FlaskForm):
  username = StringField('username', validators=[InputRequired()])
  password = PasswordField('password')

@app.route('/form', methods=['GET','POST'])
def form():
  form=LoginForm()
  return render_template('form.html', form=form)


if __name__== '__main__':
  app.run(debug=True)
```

The html code is as below:

```
<html>
<title> MY FORM </title>
<body>
<form method="POST" action="{{ url_for('form') }}">
  {{form.csrf_token}}
  {{ form.username.label }}
  {{ form.username }}
  <ul>
  {% for error in form.username.errors %}
    <li style="color: red;">{{ error }} </li>

  {% endfor %}
  </ul>
  {{ form.password }}
  {{ form.password.label }}
  <input type="submit" value="Submit">

</form>
</body>
</html>
```

Apparently, the for loop is skipped and nothing happens on clicking the submit button while the user field is null

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming that your form will be sent with POST method you have to validate the form data if they have been submitted. With flask-wtf it is really simple:

```
@app.route('/form', methods=['GET','POST'])
def check_form():
    form = LoginForm()
    if form.validate_on_submit():
        # do something
        return # something 
    return render_template('form.html', form=form)
```

I invite you to read more about [flask-wtf](http://flask-wtf.readthedocs.io/en/stable/quickstart.html)

Answer (score 1):

You are not validating the form at all in the `form` function. Edit the function and add a validation line. It is after validation that the errors are found. Otherwise, the `form` variable in your template will not have errors attributes. The following should do:

```
@app.route('/form', methods=['GET','POST'])
def form():
    this_form = LoginForm()
    this_form.validate()
    return render_template('form.html', form=this_form)
```

Also, avoid naming your form `form` since you already named the function `form`. You should change either the function name or the variable name for the form.

I hope this helps.